# Using SuperTest and Jest to test TypeScript Apollo Server: 'request.post' is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to use SuperTest to test an Apollo Server following the first answer to [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42542917/unit-tests-for-graphql-node-js-app), among other examples I've found.

My code in its entirety is

```
//     /__test__/index.test.ts

import * as request from 'supertest';

    let postData = {
        query: `query allArticles{
                    allArticles{
                        id
                    }
                }`,
        operationName: 'allArticles'
    };

    test('basic', async () => {
        try {
            const response = request
                .post('/graphql')
                .send(postData)
                .expect(200); // status code that you expect to be returned
            console.log('response', response);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(`error ${error.toString()}`);
        }
    });
```

However when I run this with Jest

```
"test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --colors"
```

I get

```
 PASS  __test__/index.test.ts
  ● Console

    console.log
    error TypeError: request.post is not a function

      at __test__/index.test.ts:20:11
```

For what it's worth, I don't think it's "passing" the test, as it doesn't matter what I put in the `expect`.

If I change my code to follow the Stack Overflow exactly (passing the GraphQL endpoint directly to request

```
  test('basic', async () => {
            try {
                const response = request('/graphql')
                    .post('/graphql')
                    .send(postData)
                    .expect(200); // status code that you expect to be returned
                console.log('response', response);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`error ${error.toString()}`);
            }
        });
```

I get

```
PASS  __test__/index.test.ts
  ● Console

    console.log
      error TypeError: request is not a function

      at __test__/index.test.ts:20:11
```

I'm using `ts-jest`, and running under Node 12.14

My `tsconfig.json` is

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES6",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.test.ts",
    "**/*.mock.ts"
  ]
}
```

and my `jest.config` is

```
module.exports = {
    preset: 'ts-jest',
    testEnvironment: 'node'
};
```

Any clues appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`supertest` has no export, which is why need to change your import to

```
import {default as request} from 'supertest';
```

`request` is now the exported factory function which you can invoke:

```
const response = request('/graphql')
                    .post('/graphql')
...
```